# pyqt dynamic update of property and css

Tags: python, css, pyqt5

I'm trying to create an alert label that changes color based on some system state

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget,  QVBoxLayout, QLabel, QPushButton

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("My App")
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.lbl1 = QLabel("text")
        self.lbl2 = QLabel("!!!!")
        btn = QPushButton("Alert")
        btn.clicked.connect(self.update)

        layout.addWidget(self.lbl1)
        layout.addWidget(self.lbl2)
        layout.addWidget(btn)

        self.lbl1.setProperty("alert", False)
        self.lbl2.setProperty("alert", True)

        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

    def update(self, item):
        print("update alert")
        self.lbl1.setProperty("alert", True)
        

CSS = """
QLabel[alert="true"] { background-color: yellow}
"""

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setStyleSheet(CSS)

window = MainWindow()
window.show()

app.exec()
```

I can use a custom property and CSS to correctly set the background of the 2nd label to yellow in the `__init__`. The 1st label should be set to yellow on clicking the alert button but nothing happens.

Is there some update or redraw function that also needs to be called?

Comment: The [documentation is clear on the point](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types): "**Warning:** If the value of the Qt property changes after the style sheet has been set, it might be necessary to force a style sheet recomputation. One way to achieve this is to unset the style sheet and set it again.".

Comment: Missed that: adding `app.setStyleSheet(CSS)` at the end of update fixes it.

Comment: Use that approach with extreme care, as it causes **any** existing widgets to check for their style (if they have/had a stylesheet, no matter if inherited or not) and eventually cause repaints for all of them. If you just need to change the text color of a label, then use a custom property or a function.